# Google map not showing my current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I wrote code in Android studio to display my location in a Google Map fragment but it is not doing so. The map is being displayed but the coordinates I want is not getting marked. The code is the following:

```
public class SEMapTab extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private View rootView;
private MapFragment mMapFrag;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_entity_map, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mMapFrag == null) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

        mMapFrag = (MapFragment) fragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        mMapFrag.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    //if network provider is enabled
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                double Latitude= location.getLatitude();    //Get latitude

                double Longitude = location.getLongitude();     //Get longitude

                LatLng latLng= new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

                //Map latitude and longitude
                mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).fillColor(Color.BLUE).radius(10));

                //Zoom in to current location
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,18));


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });

    }
    //else if gps provider is enabled
    else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                double Latitude= location.getLatitude();    //Get latitude

                double Longitude = location.getLongitude();     //Get longitude

                LatLng latLng= new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

                //Map latitude and longitude
                mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).fillColor(Color.BLUE).radius(10));

                //Zoom in to current location
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,18));



            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }



}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{

}
}
```

I have also included the necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

The Map fragment is opening but there is no circle getting marked at my current location. Alternatively, if I hard code a GPS location in OnMapReady function, then that is gettig marked and is working fine. I request you to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Print the latitude and longitude returned by LocationManager to the console. Are you running your app in an emulator?

Comment: I am running it on both, emulator and phone. It is the same output.

Comment: What coordinates are being printed in the console?

Comment: D/GPS: 37.421998333333335 -122.08400000000002   These are being printed. I added the line                     Log.d("GPS",Double.toString(Latitude)+" "+Double.toString(Longitude)+"\n");
 in both the places where the latitude and longitude of the current location is being procured

Comment: Ok great, that means the problem is related to putting the circle on the map rather than location manager returning weird coordinates

Comment: I am still not able to figure out why it is not able to put the circle on the map. Is it because of the onMapReady function ? You could give your solution to this issue (as well as the reason why the circle is not being displayed) as an answer below instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

At `onMapReady` add `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`. No need to handle "manually" the location manager and these providers. Just be sure that user has given the permission to the app to access his location before call this, otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: I need to do it using the location manager because eventually, I will need to send this location (Latitude, Longitude) to a database. The solution you gave is a pragmatic fix but could you tell me what is the problem with the code I wrote?

Comment: I dont know what is wrong with your solution since i have never experienced with these APIs, but to achieve what you want i would use GoogleApiClient and LocationServices. These Apis are proposed by google in order to get user's location and listen for location updates. A nice example can be found here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates. Google has taken care for all these in order you (the developer) does not need to handle the location sensors and other low level stuff.

Comment: The error is in the mMap.addCircle() and mMap.moveCamera() functions. The GPS coordinates are being printed in the debug log when I add Log.d("GPS",Double.toString(Latitude)+" "+Double.toString(Longitude)+"\n"); .                See if you could use this info to figure out the error.

Comment: Are you sure that your map has been loaded when you add the circle?

Comment: Where do you init mMap map object?

Comment: I haven't.. But how do I initialize the mMap map object outside the onMapChanged function?? Is there a constructor for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153553/discussion-between-antonis-lat-and-thanatos).